# Terminal PATH has disappeared OSX - how to reset?

Tags: terminal, path, environment-variables, canopy

Something has happened to my $PATH variable -- how do i reset it to its initial settings?

If I run the command

```
$ cat /etc/paths
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Then this is all correct. But when I run the command

```
$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Users/sdev/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

I tried to fix this by using

```
export pathname
```

Need to restore to what it ought to be: I should just have this pathname when i run echo $PATH. I uninstalled Canopy which I thought would solve the problem.

```
/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset your `PATH` back to just `/usr/bin/` put this in `~/.bash_rc`

```
export PATH="/usr/bin/"
```

Or whatever you want between the quotes. Then you can run `source ~/.bash_rc` in terminal and the path will be set to what you set it as in `.bash_rc`.